# How to check if a viewStub is already inflated?

Tags: android, view, viewstub

I did not find any boolean method does this task. Can I do this by checking if the `id` of the `viewStub`changed to the one specified as `inflatedid`?

Javacode:

```
    protected void plantViewTree() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewStub mViewstub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub00);

            if (mViewStub is inflated) {
              //do somthing
              }else
               mViewstub.inflate();

}
```

***Update***
**Comments on th eOutput**

According to this code, the `toast` always displays its message, which mean since `mViewStub` is assigned to `findViewById` it is never null except the `viewstub` view in the underlaying alyout is not available. Any suggestions.?

```
protected void plantViewTree() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewStub mViewstub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.viewStub00);
    if (mViewstub != null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "view is inflated", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        mViewstub.inflate();
}
```

Comment: If it is not inflated, it will be null. You can check if it is null or not.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We can view the `ViewStub` source code, the most important method is `inflate()`,

```
 public View inflate() {
    final ViewParent viewParent = getParent();

    if (viewParent != null && viewParent instanceof ViewGroup) {
        if (mLayoutResource != 0) {
            final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewParent;
            final LayoutInflater factory;
            if (mInflater != null) {
                factory = mInflater;
            } else {
                factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            }
            final View view = factory.inflate(mLayoutResource, parent,
                    false);

            if (mInflatedId != NO_ID) {
                view.setId(mInflatedId);
            }

            final int index = parent.indexOfChild(this);
            parent.removeViewInLayout(this);

            final ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
            if (layoutParams != null) {
                parent.addView(view, index, layoutParams);
            } else {
                parent.addView(view, index);
            }

            mInflatedViewRef = new WeakReference<View>(view);

            if (mInflateListener != null) {
                mInflateListener.onInflate(this, view);
            }

            return view;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ViewStub must have a valid layoutResource");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ViewStub must have a non-null ViewGroup viewParent");
    }
}
```

Notice this line `parent.removeViewInLayout(this)` ,it had removed in layout after inflate.so we can check if a viewStub is already inflated by this way.

```
if (mViewStub.getParent() != null) {
    mViewStub.inflate();
} else {
    mViewStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: to see does viewstub finish it's work just check, mViewStub.getParent() != null, if it is not finish it's work parent will be != null otherwise parent will be null

Answer (score 7):

```
if (mViewStub.getParent() != null) { 
    //have not been inflated
    mViewStub.inflate();
} else { 
    //already inflated
}
```

Answer (score 3):

note from google:

> When a ViewStub is made visible, or when inflate() is invoked, the
>   layout resource is inflated.

so you can check the visibility (or even checking if it's "null").

Comment: that is not true, viewstub is not null when it is inflated

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension:

```
/**
 * To prevent crash when we try inflate view that was already inflated. Because OS delete ViewStub by inflating.
 */
fun ViewStub?.safeInflate() {
    if (this?.parent != null) inflate()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more simple approach, in Kotlin:

```
if (viewStub != null) {
   viewStub.isVisible = true
} else {
   // The view has been inflated already.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in Kotlin.. i know that it uses tag (its not cool) but its easy to use.
this is kotlin extension function:

```
fun ViewStub.doInflate(init: View.() -> Unit = {}, action: (View) -> Unit = {}) {
val isInflated = (tag as? Boolean) ?: false
if (!isInflated) {
    setOnInflateListener { _, view ->
        this.tag = true
        init.invoke(view)
        action.invoke(view)
    }
    this.inflate()
} else {
    action.invoke(this.rootView)
}
```

}

and you can use it like this :

```
 myViewStub.doInflate({
            //code that run with initialisation
        }, {
           //code that run if stub already inflated
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation suggests, we should not keep a long lived reference to the ViewStub, and android also allows assigning an `inflatedId` to ViewStub, which comes into existence once its inflated

so we can have a function signature like `getInflatedView(): View`

```
fun getInflatedView(@LayoutRes layoutId: Int): View {
    val stub: ViewStub? = findViewById(R.id.stubId)
    stub?.layoutResource = layoutId
    return stub?.inflate() ?: findViewById(R.id.inflatedId)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Calling `yourViewStub.visibility(View.VISIBLE)` you don´t need to check if it´s inflated or not.

Comment: Got the same crush.